# Is Azure Active Directory default directory for azure while in Free Subscription? How can to delete default directory?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I have created a Azure Active Directory B2C directory and changed my Azure Free Subscription from Default Directory to this new B2C directory.

Trying to delete the Default Directory, but not able to do it, getting error **Directory has one or more Azure subscriptions**

Even tried resolution in this [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/2967860/you-can-t-delete-a-directory-through-the-azure-management-portal) but did't work, please help can you provide screenshots on how to do it.

Please help I am new to Azure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey there Vigneshwaran,

If You are unable to delete an Azure Active Directory (AAD) with the error message: “Directory has one or more subscriptions to Microsoft Online Services.” In that case, it is not possible to delete the directory through the Azure Management Portal.

you can check out the link: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pkirchner/2016/01/29/how-to-delete-an-azure-active-directory-connected-to-microsoft-online-services/

and PowerShell delete the active directory, check out this too http://www.edutech.me.uk/microsoft/identity-and-access-management/active-directory/how-to-delete-windows-azure-active-directory-waad/